# How do I setup software RAID 0 or JBOD with BTRFS?

Tags: lubuntu, 15.04, raid, btrfs, eeepc

I've a 4GB SSD drive which is BTRFS formatted and is running Lubuntu 15.04 and a 8GB SD card (which I've always inserted) formatted as BTRFS. I want to setup software RAID 0 or JBOD, so I've more space, but I don't know how. Or must I use another distro?

Comment: RAID  is a data storage virtualization technology that combines multiple disk drive components into a single logical unit for the purposes of performance improvement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read more about Raid here: [RAID levels](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_RAID_levels)

You could use 4+4GB space, if you run it as raid 0, so 8gb in total. The risk of failure will be like 10 times higher with this configuration.

You could also run JBOD instead of RAID 0, which will result in 12GB of usable space.

What I would recommend: Mount the SD-Card as `/home`. This will give you 4GB for the system, and 8GB in your home, where all your user specific data is beeing stored.

Comment: Does JBOD work with BTRFS?

Comment: RAID is filesystem-independent.

Comment: OK, I would try JBOD. But how do I set it up on Lubuntu 15.04?